# Does jenkins xcode plugin support iOS 11 Apps

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can I build iOS 11 apps using Jenkins xcode plugin?. 
If can from which version Onwards?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it's only getting installed on ios 10. Is it due to Xcode plugin doesn't support ios 11 or do I need to change any configurations?